# How to flatten file structure of published NPM module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I have a TypeScript project that I am publishing as an NPM module. The output of compiling the project is in the directory `{mymodule}/dist/src/...` which means that when I publish, the NPM module also takes the above file structure.

The drawback to this is when individual modules needs to be required, it would look like this:

```
var individualModule = require('/dist/src');
```

I would like to flatten the output of the published module, where the files in the published module will be `{mymodule}/...` instead of `{mymodule}/dist/src/...`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the correct way of doing this is to intentionally expose modules from your package via `module.exports` (or `import/export`) in the root file.

```
const exposableOne = require('/dist/src/ex-1.js');
const exposableTwo = require('/dist/src/ex-2.js');

// ...

module.exports = { mymodule, exposableOne, exposableTwo };
```

You can take a look at the main [Express framework file](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js) - they doing almost the same thing using `exports.` directive.

Not exactly TypeScript stuff but idea is quite common.

**UPDATE:**

If you really need to do this without binding via `require/exports`, than you could use the symlinks approach. I'm not sure that this option works well on all platforms, but for an example you can check this [solved issue](https://github.com/cook-pkg/cook/issues/2) and [this repository](https://github.com/cook-pkg/core) on GitHub. `aliases` directory in the latter contains files that are symlinked to the `recipes` directory modules.

Comment: This actually describes my current set up, but not my desired set up. With this set-up, code using my library would have to do something like `var mylib = require('mylib').exposableOne`...but this is not what I want, I want the exposable to be required with something like `var exposableOne = require('mylib/exposableOne')`